# Incorporating JS classes into react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class

Just need someone to tell me if i'm going about this the wrong way. Was doing react dev then decided to incorporate structure for ease of reading and catch mistakes so implemented ES6 classes and typescript.

My reasoning behind the following is:

- In react i'm using useState() which has to be passed an object so i'm returning the instance of the class
- I used a class instead of a dictionary like the link below because it doesn't return a string for the user error so I didn't think it was as succinct.

https://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2016/06/09/implementing-a-dictionary-in-typescript

```
import { isEmptyOrSpace } from "../projectServices/functions";

export class EmailList {
    constructor (private _emailList:string[] = []) { }

    //#region Fields and Props
    public get emailList() : string[] {
        return this._emailList;
    }
    public set emailList(v : string[]) {
        this._emailList = v;
    }

    public validateEmail = (email:string):boolean => {
        const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }
    
        public EmailChecks = (email:string):string => {
        if (isEmptyOrSpace(email)) { return 'Please enter an email.';}
        if (!this.validateEmail(email)) { return `'${email}' is not in the correct format for an email.`;}
        if (this.emailList.includes(email)) { return `'${email}' already exists in your list of emails to add.`;}
        return '';
    }

    public addEmail = (email:string):EmailList => {
        let result = this.emailList;
        result.concat([email]);
        this.emailList = result;
        return this
    }
    //#endregion
}
```

Couldn't find any examples online of people using ES6 classes with typescript and react so improvised.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: what have you tried so far in react? what isn't working? what is actually happening and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: Model classes are totally fine. `validateEmail` should probably be a `static` method, though. And you really don't need getters/setters in javascript until you actually use them for something. Just make a `public emailList: string[]` property.

Comment: Cheers guys just needed a sense check that returning this seems sensible and thanks for the heads up on the getters and setter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this looks totally fine, In other programming languages it is common to pass around a class object. I would personally construct my data like this too, especially for complex data needs.